# Google Translate - How to remove annoying header and pop up textboxes from my website

Tags: translation, google-translate

So I installed Google Translate on my website. But when the language is translated to a different language there is an annoying header that pops up on top and there are annoying text box pop ups showing suggestions everytime users scroll over any text.  How can I remove these 2 annoying features? Thank you in advance for anyone who helps!

Answer (score 0):

Right click inside the page you've translated with Google and Left Click "This Frame" then Left Click "Show Only This Frame"